# How to create fixed amount of UITableViewCell and if the data is null then row should be not be shown

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using tableView to display some information which is just four line of information. And i want to assign respective information to each row.
Like  how shown in the below image there are four rows, same as in the image so i am using tableView for that. Here my problem is that i have created four cells but don't know how should i use label in specific cell and show the info.
and also if the value is null that row should not be there means if two values among four are null then only two rows having values should be there in tableView. How can i achieve this. Till now i am only able to show one row information only.

[image]

```
- (NSArray *)myTableViewCells
{
     if (!_myTableViewCells)
     {
         _myTableViewCells = @[
                              [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil],
                              [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil],
                              [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil],
                              [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil]

                              ];
       }

       return _myTableViewCells;
}

   if([managedObject valueForKey:@"personality_company_master_values"] != nil)
{
    [_displayValues addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Personality    %@",[managedObject valueForKey:@"personality_company_master_values"]]];
}
 if([managedObject valueForKey:@"video_tag"] != nil)
{
    [_displayValues addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tag                 %@",[managedObject valueForKey:@"video_tag"]]];
}

 if([managedObject valueForKey:@"industry_master_values"] != nil)
{
    [_displayValues addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Industry       %@",[managedObject valueForKey:@"industry_master_values"]]];
}



- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
     return self.myTableViewCells.count;
}

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
  UITableViewCell* cell = self.myTableViewCells[indexPath.row];

   //   NSManagedObject *managedObject = [self.devices lastObject];

     cell.backgroundColor = [self colorFromHexString:@"#014455"];


   cell.textLabel.text = _displayValues[indexPath.row];

   cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [self colorFromHexString:@"#014455"];

   cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

   cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];


   //  UILabel *lbl=(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:900];

   //   [lbl setText:[managedObject valueForKey:@"personality_company_master_values"]];

   //   lbl.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];

return cell;
  }
```

Comment: it would probably be easier to use a storyboard tableviewcontroller with static cells (as apposed to prototype cells), then you dont need to implement the tableviews delegate methods like this, and can just link directly to the labels etc in the cells

Comment: @Fonix  my class is UIViewContoller and static cells should be embed in UITableViewController so do i have to use a custom class for this or i how can i do this, can you please explain me in detail. i am quite new here.

Comment: does your UIViewController need to be one? if the table takes up the whole screen just swap it to a UITableViewController, if you really do need a UIViewController, you can embed a UITableviewController into your UIViewController via the storyboard type "container view", just then the labels/cells etc wont be directly accessible to your UIViewController and will have to be accessed via this embedded UITableViewController. unfortunately i dont have the time to explain how to do this in detail

Comment: no it noes not takes up the whole screen its just takes up 30% if screen @Fonix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the value you want display in an array.
    Something like this

```
@property (monatomic, strong)NSMuatableArray *displayValues;


-(void)viewDidLoad
{

    self.displayValues =  [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSManagedObject *managedObject = [self.devices lastObject];

    if([managedObject valueForKey:@"personality_company_master_values"] != nil)
    {
    [self.displayValues addObject:[managedObject valueForKey:@"personality_company_master_values"]];
    }
    if([managedObject valueForKey:@"company_master_values"] != nil)
    {
    [self.displayValues addObject:[managedObject valueForKey:@"company_master_values"]];
    }

    if([managedObject valueForKey:@"tag_master_values"] != nil)
    {
    [self.displayValues addObject:[managedObject valueForKey:@"tag_master_values"]];
    }
}






          - (NSArray *)myTableViewCells
                 {
                 if (!_myTableViewCells)
                 {
                     _myTableViewCells = @[
                                          [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil],
                                          [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil],
                                          [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil],
                                          [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil]

                                          ];
                   }

                    return _myTableViewCells;
                   }


                 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
                 {
                    return self.displayValues.count;
                  }

                     - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
                 {
                UITableViewCell* cell = self.myTableViewCells[indexPath.row];
                // NSManagedObject *managedObject = [self.devices lastObject];

                //cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[managedObject valueForKey:@"personality_company_master_values"]];
                cell.textLabel.text = self.displayValues[indexPath.row];
                   //not getting have to do this way or any other way please help  

                   // secondLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[managedObject valueForKey:@"company_master_values"]];

                   // thirdLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[managedObject valueForKey:@"tag_master_values"]];        

                return cell;
                }
```

Comment: Updated the code, make displayValues as Property and load the Values in ViewDidLoad.

Comment: thanks a ton man it worked for me now i am getting the right side of the image which i have added while asking the question. How to get the left side should i add label on left side manually from storyboard and hide them when the value is nil. or is there is any other way to do that because i have to show the colours also,  same as like in the image.

Comment: Add a Label in storyboard and change the displayValues content from string to some Model of 2 variables LeftLabel and RightLabel and load the displayValues with Model in viewDidLoad and similarly get the Model back in cellForRowAtIndexPath in assigning the values to left and right labels.

Comment: sorry but i did not get you what you are exactly saying,  i am currently doing it this way       [_displayValues addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Personality    %@",[managedObject valueForKey:@"personality_company_master_values"]]];   but the problem is how to set two different background colours for the same cell and the text color to white also. @Amit Kalghathi

Comment: do something like this.. cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor]; //Similar to this...  if you have two different labels set for each label Background.

Comment: should i add two label in the cell it self and change the background color @Amit Kalghatgi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117288/discussion-between-amit-kalghatgi-and-vicky).

Comment: not able use label and set two colours @Amit Kalghatgi

Comment: Where is the Other label?

Comment: actually i am not adding other label i am writing it using string format string format updated code

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you're doing several things wrong, starting with preallocating an array of cells.  Tableviews don't work like that, you provide cells on demand and populate them with values from your data model.  When you want to remove a cell update your data model then call `reloadData()`.  Here's a simple example:

```
import UIKit

class MyCell: UITableViewCell {
    var row: Int = -1   // serves no purpose but to show how you might subclass a UITableViewCell
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    var dataModel = [
        "Hello", "World,", "this", "is", "a", "tableview"
    ]

    var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var frame = view.bounds
        let statusBarHeight = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.height

        frame.origin.y += statusBarHeight
        frame.size.height -= statusBarHeight

        tableView = UITableView(frame: frame, style: .Plain)
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        tableView.registerClass(MyCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "mycell")

        view.addSubview(tableView)
    }

    // MARK: - UITableViewDataSource

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataModel.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("mycell") as! MyCell
        let row = indexPath.row

        cell.row = row    // there is no point in doing this other than to show it as an example
        cell.textLabel!.text = dataModel[row]

        return cell
    }

    // MARK: - UITableViewDelegate

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        dataModel.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

*EDIT:* Here's an objective c version

```
////////////////////////////
///  Objective C Version  //
////////////////////////////

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface MyCell: UITableViewCell

@property(assign) NSInteger row;    // serves no purpose but to show how you might subclass a UITableViewCell

@end

@implementation MyCell @end


@interface ViewController() <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property NSMutableArray *dataModel;
@property UITableView *tableView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _dataModel = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: @[@"Hello", @"World,", @"this", @"is", @"a", @"tableview"]];

    CGRect frame = self.view.bounds;
    CGFloat statusBarHeight = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height;

    frame.origin.y += statusBarHeight;
    frame.size.height -= statusBarHeight;

    _tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame: frame style: UITableViewStylePlain];
    _tableView.delegate = self;
    _tableView.dataSource = self;

    [_tableView registerClass: [MyCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier: @"mycell"];

    [self.view addSubview: _tableView];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return _dataModel.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyCell *cell = (MyCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"mycell"];
    NSInteger row = indexPath.row;

    cell.row = row;    // there is no point in doing this other than to show it as an example
    cell.textLabel.text = _dataModel[row];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [_dataModel removeObjectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
    [_tableView reloadData];
}

@end
```

Comment: p.s. - I'll add there are generally better ways to do things here, such as not calculating the status bar height and using instead edge layouts, constraints, etc.  My goal was to show a simple, pared-down example of a `UITableView` implementation to get you going.

Comment: p.p.s - If you'd like me to write an objective-c version I could do that.  It's been a while and I'm thinking entirely in swift these days but regardless of which language you use the calls and setup are all the same.

Comment: it would be great if you write in objective c @par

Comment: I added an objective c version.  that took longer than I thought, don't get out of swift much these days.  good luck!

Comment: i knew this how to use the table view and populat the data but the problem in front of me was that i want to show piece of information from core data in the small table view. I could't take it into array thats why i was thinking to if there is way to directly use four cells and assign data to four labels or the rows directly

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to create a fixed amount of cells this is not an efficient solution to the problem. You should create NSMutableDictionary and save the data like this:

```
NSMutableArray *data = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[data setValue:@"Vijayakanth" forKey:@"Personality"];
```

Now in the table view delegate you can return the keys count for noOfRowsInSection and in cellForRowAtIndexPath you can get the key from dictionary get the value w.r.t that key and assign the values to your cell. In your case:

```
Key: Personality (which is shown on the left side)
Value: Vijayakanth (which is shown on the right side)
```

Hope you understand the point.

Comment: No but the data is variable and i am getting it from core data and the key is not set there i have to set it now.Means i cannot set value setValue:@"Vijayakanth" forKey:@"Personality"];  like this for key personality because it is not specified anywhere i have to add it manually like this       [_displayValues addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Personality    %@",[managedObject valueForKey:@"personality_company_master_values"]]];  but don't know how to set the two different background colours of the same row.

Comment: @vicky the point is not to create a fixed number of cells as they are automatically reused in terms of memory management. We can create a data according to the need and use it accordingly